# Append string in the middle of a query in python

Tags: python, string, format

I'm trying to build a query in python, I'm looking for an elegant way to append a WHERE condition in the middle of a string:

```
def get_raw_queryset(frequency=None, where_condition=None):
    qs = "SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS count FROM user_transaction_log " \
         # I WANT TO APPEND A WHERE ONLY IF not None
         if where_condition:
             "WHERE .... = 1" \
         "GROUP BY type , strftime('{0}', datetime) ORDER BY id" \
         .format(frequency)
    return qs
```

Answer (score 4):

This will work as long as you can safely evaluate the WHERE string even if `where_condition` is not a string:

```
"SELECT ..." + bool(where_condition) * ("WHERE ...") + "GROUP ..."
```

I hope you're being extremely careful to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: I'm using django and this is a function on my backend. Should I worry?

Comment: @GustavoReyes it depends on whether user input is used to construct that condition.

Comment: Then we're fine :)